Pull Request stuck on "Expected — Waiting for status to be reported" when I want to skip certain jobs. Unsure how to skip while still reporting status
I have this workflow in a monorepo (frontend / backend / automated tests) that runs for every pull request. I want to not deploy frontend/backend when just making changes to Cypress tests so I have added path-ignore which works. However, now pull requests with just changes only changes in those path-ignore folders get blocked by the following:
Questions E2E Test / build-and-test Expected — Waiting for status to be reported

This is the code at the end of E2E workflow, even though it doesn't run it still somehow expects a status:
  - name: Check for Report Files
        id: check_report
        run: |
          if [ -f backend/reports/junit.xml ]; then
            echo "report_exists=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          else
            echo "report_exists=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          fi

      - name: Upload Report to artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        if: env.report_exists == 'true'
        with:
          name: e2e-report.${{ github.run_id }}.${{ github.run_number }}.${{ github.run_attempt }}
          path: backend/reports/junit.xml

      - name: Clear connection
        if: success() || failure()
        run: |
          pkill -9 -f start-iap-tunnel

      - name: Test Report
        id: e2e_test_report
        uses: dorny/test-reporter@v1
        if: env.report_exists == 'true'
        with:
          name: Questions E2E Tests
          path: backend/reports/*.xml
          reporter: jest-junit

      - name: Notify on PR
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && (success() || failure()) && steps.e2e_test_report.outputs.url_html != ''
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            await github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: `### E2E Questions test report overview

              | Passed ✅     | Failed ❌     | Skipped |
              | ------------- |:-------------:| -------:|
              | ${{ steps.e2e_test_report.outputs.passed }}  | ${{ steps.e2e_test_report.outputs.failed }} | ${{ steps.e2e_test_report.outputs.skipped }} |
              
              **Report link:** ${{ steps.e2e_test_report.outputs.url_html }}

              `
            });

And here is the pull request workflow:
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    paths-ignore:
      - '.github/**'
      - 'cypress-tests/**'
      - 'api-tests/**'
jobs:
  questions-e2e-test:
    name: Questions E2E Test
    uses: ./.github/workflows/job-questions-e2e-test.yml
    with:
      WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER_DEV: ${{ vars.WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER_DEV }}
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT_DEV: ${{ vars.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_DEV }}
    secrets:
      token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

  deploy-preview-backend:
    name: Deploy backend preview
    uses: ./.github/workflows/backend-deploy-preview.yml
    with:
      WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER_DEV: ${{ vars.WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER_DEV }}
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT_DEV: ${{ vars.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_DEV }}
      DEPLOY_CHANNEL_ID_DEV: ${{ github.head_ref == 'pentest' && 'pentest' || format('pr{0}', github.event.pull_request.number) }}

  deploy-preview-frontend:
    name: Deploy frontend preview
    uses: ./.github/workflows/frontend-deploy-preview.yml
    with:
      WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER_DEV: ${{ vars.WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER_DEV }}
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT_DEV: ${{ vars.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_DEV }}
      DEPLOY_CHANNEL_ID_DEV: ${{ github.head_ref == 'pentest' && 'pentest' || format('pr{0}', github.event.pull_request.number) }}
 

  send-message:
    needs: [deploy-preview-frontend, deploy-preview-backend]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ always() && contains(needs.*.result, 'success') && !(contains(needs.*.result, 'failure')) && !(contains(needs.*.result, 'cancelled')) }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Notify pull request
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }},
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: `Deployed to ${{ format('https://{0}.preview.dev', format('pr{0}', github.event.pull_request.number)) }}`
            })

